# Is there any reason why declaring a variable default outside of a method would be better or worse than defining a default in a no-arg constructor

Tags: java, variables, memory

Is there any reason to one way over the other?

```
public ExampleClass{
    private exampleVariable = 1;
    public ExampleClass(){

    }
}
```

over

```
public ExampleClass{

    public ExampleClass(){
    private exampleVariable = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are minor differences, yes. But for the most cases, it is a matter of stylel

Comment: The second form doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

The second option will not even compile.  The second variable is a local variable and cannot be private.  A local variable will only exist within the function where it is created.  The first option defines a field, which can exist as long as the owning object exists.